# Writing a line in a file when finding a keyword

Tags: python

I am trying to **make a function** which writes a line when it finds some text inside a file. 
**Example**: it finds "hello" in a .txt file so then writes "Hi!" in the following line. *There is something else*, i want it to write "Hi!" **not the first time** it finds "hello" **but the second**.
Here is what i have been trying, but i don't know if the idea is right. Any help?

```
def line_replace(namefilein):
    print namefilein
    filein=open(namefilein, "rw")
    tag="intro"
    filein.read()
    for line in filein:
        if tag=="second" or tag=="coord":
            try:
                filein.write("\n\n %s" %(text-to-be-added))
                print line
            except:
                if tag=="coord":    
                    tag="end"
                else:
                    tag="coord"

        if "           text-to-find" in line:
            if tag=="intro":
                tag="first"
            elif tag=="first":
                tag="second"
    filein.close()
```

Comment: do you need to use the same file for input and output?

Comment: and do you mean that just the first time is ignored, and what if it find several times 'hello'?

Comment: Yes, the outfile is the input file with the line added by the function.

Comment: In principle i need to ignore only once, because the keyword appears only two times. It would be good to make a general function to replace some specific time

Comment: I have added an answer that I think will help you, so let me know if this helped you

Comment: great, i will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
def line_replace(namefilein):

    new_content = ''
    first_time = False
    with open(namefilein, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            new_content += line
            if 'hello' in line:
                if first_time:
                    new_content += 'Hi!' + '\n'
                else:
                    first_time = True


    with open(namefilein, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_content)
```

Look that I am using the `with` statement that in Python is a context manager, so it means, in this case, when the block of code has executed, then the file will be closed automatically.

Let's supposed you have a file `my_file.txt` which contents is:

```
hello
friend
this
is
hello
```

And let's say your file is in the same directory than the python file that has your code, so calling:

```
line_replace('my_file.txt')
```

will produce the following output:

```
hello
friend
hello
Hi!
is
```

Comment: great, i will try it